# What kind of side effects does libgdx numSamples have

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am trying to render some 512x512 image in a 50x50 square area in my viewport and I use Linear texture filtering. My virtual viewport size is 550x800 px. So the square area, in which the texture is drawn, is scaled according to screen resolution.

```
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

On a Samsung Galaxy S3 whose screen resolution is 720x1280 texture is drawn smoothly and it is satisfactory.

But on a Samsung Galaxy S2 whose screen resolution is 480x800 texture still have aliasing problems. I made some search on the web and found `numSamples` parameter of `AndroidApplicationConfiguration`

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.numSamples = 5;
```

In [libgdx documentation](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html#numSamples) it says *"2 is a good value"* but I am unable to have smooth renderings till a `numSamples` value of `5`

My question is; what kind of side effects may cause having `cfg.numSamples = 5` in terms of performance, battery usage, cpu overheating etc.?

Comment: Generally speaking, `5` is a bad value for anything having to do with anti-aliasing. MSAA modes only come in powers of 2. Commonly implemented MSAA sample counts are 1,2,4,8,16. With 8 and 16 being reserved for the highest-end desktop GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

numSamples is the number of Anti-aliasing samples. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing for more information.

You may want to look into mipmapping (TextureFilter.MipMap{Nearest/Linear}{Nearest/Linear}) texture filters. TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest or TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear will probably give you better looking textures, but you need to ensure that you set the useMipMaps flag in the Texture constructor to "true" to generate mipmaps.